# Grails/MySQL field length constraint

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 1.3.7 and MySQL <s>5.1.</s>5.5. I have a class that defines a string property like this:

```
class Topic {
    String name;
    User owner;
    // other fields

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false, maxSize: 1024, unique: ['owner'])
    }
}
```

This works fine with the in-memory database, but when I deploy the WAR file, I get this error:

```
12/06/07 17:09:48 ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate: Unsuccessful: create table topic (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not null, date_created datetime not null, description longtext, name longtext not null, owner_id bigint not null, primary key (id), unique (owner_id, name))
12/06/07 17:09:48 ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate: BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length
```

If I change the `maxSize` spec to 255, everything works correctly.

My reading of the documentation was that MySQL could not figure out the key length by default to enforce the uniqueness constraint; why doesn't grails pass the maxSize value for that purpose?

UPDATE: 8 Jun 2012
Here is the hibernate specification I am using:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

I am using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver with the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar` library with MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Which Hibernate dialect have you specified in DataSource.groovy?

Comment: I added the hibernate and MySQL info to the question

Comment: I meant the dialect (should be MySQL5InnoDBDialect), which is specified inside the `dataSource { ... }` block in DataSource.groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of mysql are you using, Maximum length of a varchar column could be 255 (before mysql 5.0.3) - See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

You can try changing the column type to [text](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html)

Comment: I can confirm that this problem affects MySQL version 5.5.  It's happening to me using MySQL 5.5.28 and Grails 2.1.1.